# Where this javascript included?

Tags: 7, javascript

In my Drupal site I got this error in google chrome console:

```
GET http://domain.com/file?mq8c07 404 (Not Found)
```

But I can't find where this file is included, how can I find it?

Comment: What makes you think it's a javascript file?

Comment: Its inside <script> tag in my html

Comment: is it your domain.com or an external site?  if external, a lot of these get added dynamically by the likes of google/facebook/twitter/sharing sites/etc via another set of js.

Comment: Its internal, When I logged out it goes away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a lot of ways a javascript file may be included. Ex: theme.info | drupal_add_js etc. Try clear cache and if not work try to see if you delete any file or some module require any file.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is search this URL in your codes completly , if you reach bash command prompt you can  do it by **grep**   command .

Comment: It's good to also take a full SQL dump into a text .sql file, so grep could also look on a copy of your database. With php filter and full html filter, js may come from db as well as from code.